# Can I bypass Apple's in app purchase mechanism by outside billing?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

It is not a programming question. Just a clarification on the in app purchase feature in iOS.

I am planning to have an App with premium content. My App can be used only when user authenticates with credentials. Is it possible for me to provide premium content (paid content) only based on the authentication. I will need the user to make a payment through another web App.

By this only when a user has purchased premium content through another app will have access to certain part of the content. Other users will have access to non premium content.

Will apple allow this? Is any app in app store that works this way?

Comment: Assuming you finished your dev, can you tell us if you were accepted/ rejected using this method?

Comment: This is possible some 2 years ago....I was able to do that..I did this app for a customer...I dont know if this is possible or not..most probably this wont be a issue..

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/7832263/189006

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531137/iphone-app-with-or-without-appstore/7531250#7531250) it can help

Purchase outside the store, apple conditions, HTML 5 applications

Answer (score 5):

I think you are good to go as long as you don't ask the user to make a purchase within the iOS app.

The [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) states the following:

> 11.14 Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or external link in the app to purchase the approved content. Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app

Answer (score 0):

Apple wants a cut of your premium content sales. Unless you have the clout of, say, Amazon then you shouldn't expect any special treatment.